# Iterate over functions in Swift

Tags: swift

I am feeling a bit stupid... I want to get rid of code duplication and so I need to iterate over some functions (a couple of Darwin geometric ones).
But when I try

```
for function in [Darwin.acos, Darwin.cos, Darwin.sin] { print(function(1.0)) }
```

I get the error "Ambiguous use of 'acos'". I also tried `Darwin.acos(Double)` and got "Ambiguous reference to member 'acos'" and `Darwin.acos { $0 }` (and similar) without any luck.

Is it possible to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the type somewhere:

```
let functions: [(Double) -> Double] = [Darwin.acos, Darwin.cos, Darwin.sin]
for function in functions { print(function(1.0)) }
```

since the functions are overloaded for different floating point types:

```
public func acos(_: Float) -> Float
public func acos(_: Double) -> Double
public func acos(_: Float80) -> Float80
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks! That was the reason for my stupid try of using ```Darwin.acos(Double)```. Working perfectly!

Comment: Now I begin to notice that I didn't code too much in Swift over the last year... I will accept your answer as soon as the 10min are over.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [Sulthan said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399905/1187415):

In a future version of Swift these functions are also available as static functions on the floating point types, compare [SE-0246 Generic Math(s) Functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0246-mathable.md):

```
let functions = [Double.acos, Double.cos, Double.sin]
for function in functions { print(function(1.0)) }
```

You can try this now with a current Swift developer snapshot from https://swift.org/download/#snapshots.

Comment: Nice to know! Thanks!